# Auto-deploying an EC2 Image Builder recipe with AWS CLI: "You are not authorized to use the provided image."

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-imagebuilder

I have a script that creates this JSON EC2 Image Builder recipe:

```json
{
    "name": "MyRecipe",
    "description": "Create image recipe.",
    "semanticVersion": "1.1.0",
    "components": [
        {
            "componentArn": "arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:MyAccountID:component/MyComponent"
        }
    ],
    "parentImage": "ami-05d47d29a4c2d19e1"
}
```

then runs this command to deploy it:

```
aws imagebuilder create-image-recipe --cli-input-json file:///tmp/tmpuvshobis/create-recipe.json
```

The `parentImage` is supposed to point to an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS arm64 AMI.

### Success with admin account

Deployment **succeeds using an account with these permission policies**:

```
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSImageBuilderFullAcces
```

### Failure with role

But it **fails when using a role with limited permissions**:

Stderr:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateImageRecipe operation: The value supplied for parameter 'parentImage' is not valid. You are not authorized to use the provided image.
```

The role has these permissions:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:UntagResource",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:TagResource",
                "ec2:ModifyLaunchTemplate",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplateVersion",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "imagebuilder:CreateComponent",
                "imagebuilder:UpdateImagePipeline",
                "imagebuilder:CreateImageRecipe",
                "imagebuilder:StartImagePipelineExecution",
                "imagebuilder:CreateImagePipeline",
                "imagebuilder:TagResource",
                "imagebuilder:UntagResource",
                "imagebuilder:GetComponent",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeImageAttribute",
                "imagebuilder:ListImages",
                "imagebuilder:GetImage"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:MyAccountID:launch-template/lt-MyLaunchTemplate",
                "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:MyAccountID:repository/MyRepo",
                "arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:MyAccountID:image/*",
                "arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:MyAccountID:image-recipe/*/*",
                "arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:MyAccountID:image-pipeline/*",
                "arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:MyAccountID:component/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which permissions is the role missing? It's not clear from the error message.